# Write optimized code which takes following two list of dictionaries as input and gives output as final_result

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

Inputs:

```
list1 = [{'item_type':1,'value':55, 'title':'abc'},{'item_type':2,'value':43, 'title':'def'},{'item_type':3,'value':35, 'title':'ghi'}]

list2 = [{'item_type':2,'value':13, 'title':'jkl'},{'item_type':3,'value':85, 'title':'mno'}]
```

Challange1:
If the item_type is present in list2 then that should take the priority.

expected result:

```
final_result = [{'item_type':1,'value':55, 'title':'abc'},{'item_type':2,'value':13, 'title':'jkl'},{'item_type':3,'value':85, 'title':'mno'}]
```

Challange2:
It should merge list1 and list2 based on unique item_type and keep the higher 'value' dictionary.

expected result:

```
final_result = [{'item_type':1,'value':55, 'title':'abc'},{'item_type':2,'value':43, 'title':'def'},{'item_type':3,'value':85, 'title':'mno'}]
```

I have solved both the challenges,but I want to optimize this code using list comprehensive, lambda function. please help me.

this is my code

Challange1:

```
final_result = []
list1 = [{'item_type':1,'value':55, 'title':'abc'},{'item_type':2,'value':43, 'title':'def'},{'item_type':3,'value':35, 'title':'ghi'}]
list2 = [{'item_type':2,'value':13, 'title':'jkl'},{'item_type':3,'value':85, 'title':'mno'}]

for i in range(len(list1)):
    for j in range(len(list2)):
        if list1[i]['item_type'] == list2[j]['item_type']:
            if list1[i]['item_type'] < list2[j]['item_type']:
                final_result.append(list1[i])
            else:
                final_result.append(list2[j])
            break
    else:
        final_result.append(list1[i])
print(final_result)
```

Challange2:

```
final_result = []
list1 = [{'item_type':1,'value':55, 'title':'abc'},{'item_type':2,'value':43, 'title':'def'},{'item_type':3,'value':35, 'title':'ghi'}]
list2 = [{'item_type':2,'value':13, 'title':'jkl'},{'item_type':3,'value':85, 'title':'mno'}]

for i in range(len(list1)):
    for j in range(len(list2)):
        if list1[i]['item_type'] == list2[j]['item_type']:
            if list1[i]['value'] > list2[j]['value']:
                final_result.append(list1[i])
            else:
                final_result.append(list2[j])
            break
    else:
        final_result.append(list1[i])
print(final_result)
```

Comment: What the heck is `\color{red}{\verb!int!}int` supposed to be? That doesn't look anything like Python syntax.

Answer (score 1):

[`copy.deepcopy()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html) if you want a deep copy. But you can also make a shallow copy with `copy.copy()` or `newdict=dict(olddict)` or `olddict.copy()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use copy method.

```
dict_1 = { "a" : {"b": "c"}}
dict_2 = dict_1.copy()
```